# SQL Server Agent does not recognize hidden Windows File Share

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am using an SSIS package to get a text file from a secure Unix server. One of the steps in the package ftp's the file to a Windows file share using a Flat File Connection. I have specified the connection using the full path name: \\servername\foldername\filename.

The package runs fine on my development machine; however, I am experiencing a problem when the package runs as a service under SQL Server Agent. This is how it will have to run in Test and Production. The service has been given rights to the server and the folder, but since the folder is a hidden folder it has been appended with a $.

So the actual connection string for the Flat File Connection is: \\servername\foldername$\filename.

Could the dollar sign be causing the problem for SQL Server Agent?

I am running out of ideas and I have almost exhausted my search on the Internet. Stack Overflow is always my last resort. I hope someone can help.

Comment: When you say the service has been been given rights, what does that mean? The account that the agent runs under? What about the account the job is running under? Can you run agent/job under your credentials and and verify it's able to access the share?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the account has rights to the server. I do not have access to the SQL Server Agent. Only DBAs.

Comment: Welcome to stack. Please provide your error message if there is one

Comment: @HelloWorld - have you tried running the job under your credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved. There is no issue.

The job had insufficient permissions. The network administrators told us they had taken care of it, but after we had ruled everything else out, they checked again.

Comment: So, what was the issue?